# Pointer negation in C++ (!ptr == NULL)

Tags: c++, pointers, operators

I have come across the following null check for a pointer `ptr`

```
if(!ptr == NULL){
delete ptr;
ptr = NULL;
}
```

Now, apart from using `NULL` instead of the favored `nullptr`, I wonder if this code makes sense and is guaranteed to work by the implications of C++ standard.

Checking with msvc debugger, it does what it is supposed to do, i.e. execute the deletion only when ptr is different from `NULL`. But I seem fail to see why this can work when

```
if(ptr){...}
```

will work as well.

Comment: Note that you can pass a null pointer to `delete`, and then it would simply do nothing.

Comment: fwiw, both the checks are not needed, you can directly use `delete ptr; ptr = NULL;`  `delete` can handle `nullptr`

Comment: Why is it `!ptr==NULL` instead of `!(ptr==NULL)`? Genuine question

Comment: As for the style, well you have to ask the author, it's nothing we can really answer or help you with.

Comment: This is likely a programmer mistake that just happens to do the same thing as the intended result. It works because `NULL` is defined as 0.

Comment: NULL can be defined as the integer value 0, so the comparison is checking if a bool `!ptr` is equal to false (which is equivalent to 0).

Comment: if(ptr) means if(ptr != NULL)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is badly written code. Both GCC and clang emits a warning for it. Unfortunately, MSVC doesn't.

In the expression, `!ptr == NULL`, `!ptr` will evaluate `true` or `false` (a `bool` value!) depending on `ptr` is `nullptr` or not.

Then this `bool` value is compared to `NULL`, which is an implementation defined null pointer constant (its usage is discouraged, as we have `nullptr` now). The `NULL` will be converted to `bool` (becomes `false`). This `false` value is compared to the `bool` which comes from `!ptr`. This comparison happens to do expected thing.

But, presumably, the comparison is not intended this way.

The correct version could be `if (!(ptr==NULL))`. Or `if (ptr!=NULL)`. Or your simple version, `if (ptr)`.

Note, that the comparison is unnecessary (as `delete` handles `nullptr` pointers), so the code could be simply:

```
delete ptr;
ptr = nullptr;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an operator precedence problem.

[`==` has a lower precedence than `!`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), so your conditional gets parsed as `(!ptr) == NULL`, not `!(ptr == NULL)`.

That roughly results in `(ptr != NULL) == NULL`, or `!(ptr)`, which is the exact opposite of what you want.